# Select a point randomly, but without the bias of density

Tags: python

I have this distribution of points (allPoints, which is a list of lists: [[x1,y1][x2,y2][x3,y3][x4,y4]...[xn,yn]]):

[image]

From which I'd like to select points, randomly.

in Python I would do something like:

```
from random import *
point = choice(allPoints)
```

Except, I need the random pick to not be biased by the existing density. For instance, here, "choice" would tend to pick a point in the upmost-leftmost part of the plot.

How can I, in Python, get rid of this bias?
I've tried to divide the space in portions of size "div", and then, sample within this portion, but in many cases, no points exist at all and the while loop doesn't find any solution:

```
def column(matrix, i):
    return [row[i] for row in matrix]    

div = 10

min_x,max_x = min(column(allPoints,0)),max(column(allPoints,0))
min_y, max_y = min(column(allPoints,1)),max(column(allPoints,1))

zone_x_min = randint(1,div-1) * (max_x - min_x) / div + min_x
zone_x_max = zone_x_min + (max_x - min_x) / div

zone_y_min = randint(1,div-1) * (max_y - min_y) / div + min_y
zone_y_max = zone_yl_min + (max_y - min_y) / div

p = choice(allPoints)

cont = True

while cont == True:
    if (p[0] > zone_x_min and p[0] < zone_x_max) and (e[1] > zone_y_min and e[1] < zone_y_max):
        cont = False
    else:
        p = choice(allPoints)
```

what would be a correct, inexpensive (if possible) solution to this problem?

If it wasn't ridiculous, I think something like would work for me, in theory:

```
p = [uniform(min_x,max_x),uniform(min_y,max_y)]
while p not in allPoints:
    p = [uniform(min_x,max_x),uniform(min_y,max_y)]
```

Comment: So just to clarify, what you are intending to do is pick a random point on the map instead of a random point out of the set of points you already have?

Comment: Indeed, I need points from the right part and from the left to have an equal probability to be picked

Comment: You have to define the problem better before you can solve it. What do you want to select from? What kind of distribution do you want to select with?

Comment: It sounds like you want to pick a point randomly on the map with uniform probability, and then find the point in your list that is closest to the randomly selected point.

Comment: @AlexHall Actually that would give the points close to the "borders" more probabilty to be picked

Comment: @amalloy's point is an important one. If you want all parts of the map to be equally likely, you will have problems with all the regions with no points (and you'll need to figure out if the boundaries of your map are "real" or just lines drawn in such a way to encompass the existing points). If you need to select existing points only, you could weight them based on some kind of density factor, but it's not obvious what the best weighting formula would be.

Comment: Is there any chance you can us some more context? Formally, the density of points does not introduce any _bias_

Comment: This seems like a better question for math.stackexchange.com. It doesn't really have anything to do with python/programming yet.

Comment: Giving more context is tricky and probably not very relevant in the particular case (it's not a stat issue, but more a Python implementation one). I edited and added and example of what would work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually it is exactly a statistics issue. What you've written in your latest edit shows that you don't really know the statistics behind what you are trying to do. You are not trying to remove bias, because there isn't any bias in the process "uniformly select a point from among X points". You want to *introduce* bias, to avoid areas that have a large number of eligible points.

Comment: Make a kernel density estimate, then sample with the weights as 1/density?

Comment: Let's try reducing it to something simpler. Suppose you were trying to select among the 3 numbers 1, 1.01, and 2. Would you like a 1/3 chance for each of those points, or a 50% chance for 2 and a ~25% for each of 1 and 1.01?

Comment: That's a good point @amalloy

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little ill-formed, but here's a stab.

The idea is to use a gaussian kernel density estimate, then sample from your data with weights equal to the inverse of the pdf at each point.

This is not statistically justifiable in any real sense.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

#random data
x = np.random.normal(size = 200)
y = np.random.normal(size = 200)

#estimate the density
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(np.vstack([x,y]))

#calculate the inverse of pdf for each point, and normalise to sum to 1
pvector = 1/kernel.pdf(np.vstack([x,y]))/sum(1/kernel.pdf(np.vstack([x,y])))

#get a vector of indices based on your weights
np.random.choice(range(len(x)), size = 10, replace = True, p = pvector)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to randomly select a datum point from your graph.That is, one of the little black dots.

Compute a centroid, or pick a point like (1.0, 70).

Compute the distance from each point to the centroid and let that be the probability of your choice of that point.

That is if distance(P,C) is 100 and distance(Q,C) is 1 then let P be 100x more likely to be chosen. All points are eligible  to win, but the crowded ones are individually less likely (but make it up with.volume).

Comment: This makes invalid assumptions about the point distribution. Consider, for example, a bimodal sort of shape, with a few points in the center but many points far to the left or far to the right of the center. Your centroid-avoiding algorithm makes the less-dense area near the center even less likely to be selected.

Comment: The one assumption I'm making about the point distribution is that it matches what is shown above. If there were 10,000 points "stacked up" underneath one of the outliers, all having exactly the same (x,y) coordinates, yeah, that would be a surprise. But from the tone of the OP's question, he wants to introduce a bias away from the cluster at the top left. That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your initial attempt correctly, I believe there is a simple adjustment you can make to make this work.

Randomly generate an x value (0,4.5), and a y value (0,70).
Then loop through `allPoints` to find the closest dot.

This has the downside of large empty areas all converging to a single point. A way to help (not remove) this problem would be to make your random point have a range. If no dot exists in that range, randomly generate a new dot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want your selected points to be *visually* spread I can think of at least one "efficient/easy" method.

- Choose a random point (with `random.choice` for example) ;
- remove from your initial set any point that is "close"*;
- repeat until there is no point left in your set.

*This requires that you know from the beginning how dense you want your sample to be.